# Getting the first and last element of an array in CoffeeScript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

If say I have an array and I would to iterate through the array, but do something different to the first and last element. How should I do that?

Taking the below code as example, how do I alert element *a* and *e*?

```
array = [a,b,c,d,e]
for element in array
  console.log(element)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can retrieve the first and last elements by using array [destructuring](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) with a splat:

```
[first, ..., last] = array
```

This splat usage is supported in CoffeeScript >= 1.7.0.

Comment: Note that on CoffeeScript >= 1.7 you can write `[first, ..., last] = array` and it won't generate the unnecessary Array#slice call :D

Answer (score 24):

The vanilla way of accessing the first and last element of an array is the same as in JS really: using the index `0` and `length - 1`:

```
console.log array[0], array[array.length - 1]
```

CoffeeScript lets you write some nice array destructuring expressions:

```
[first, mid..., last] = array
console.log first, last
```

But i don't think it's worth it if you're not going to use the middle elements.

Underscore.js has some helper [`first`](http://underscorejs.org/#first) and [`last`](http://underscorejs.org/#last) methods that can make this more English-like (i don't want to use the phrase "self-explanatory" as i think any programmer would understand array indexing). They are easy to add to the `Array` objects if you don't want to use Underscore and you don't mind polluting the global namespace (this is what other libraries, like [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api), do):

```
Array::first ?= (n) ->
  if n? then @[0...(Math.max 0, n)] else @[0]

Array::last ?= (n) ->
  if n? then @[(Math.max @length - n, 0)...] else @[@length - 1]

console.log array.first(), array.last()
```

**Update**

This functions also allow you to get the *n* first or last elements in an array. If you don't need that functionality then the implementation would be much simpler (just the `else` branch basically).

**Update 2**

CoffeeScript [>= 1.7](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog) lets you write:

```
[first, ..., last] = array
```

without generating an unnecessary array with the middle elements :D

Comment: While your `first` and `last` prototype methods are elegant and helpful, it should be noted that they always return *arrays*, which differs from the behavior of sugar.js and underscore.js, which by default return the requested element only, and only return an array if `n` is specified (even if `n` equals 1). Therefore, I suggest you replace them with the following: 
`Array::first ?= (n) -> if n? then @splice 0, n else @[0]` and `Array::last ?= (n) -> if n? then @splice (if n >= @length then 0 else @length - n) else @[@length-1]`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0! I totally forgot about the simple case of returning just the first or the last element :(. I updated the answer based on your comment but used `Array#slice` instead of `Array#splice` to avoid modifying the original array.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post and correcting the splice/slice confusion. One more tweak that might make sense: rule out negative indices: `Array::first ?= (n) -> if n? then (if n <= 0 then [] else @slice 0, n) else @[0]` and `Array::last ?= (n) -> if n? then (if n <= 0 then [] else @slice -n) else @[@length-1]`

Comment: @mklement0, done (y). I was considering not complicating the implementation much more, but then thought that using `Math.max` could help avoid using nested `if`s and would yield a quite symmetric implementation for both `max` and `min`, so there it is :)

Answer (score 13):

The shortest way is here 
`array[-1..]`
See this thread
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/156

Comment: I upvoted this, although this would give you the last element of an array wrapped in a new array. Proper code should be `array[-1..][0]`

Comment: It's wrong as it is. Updating it to drinchev's suggestion would be worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

You can use just:

```
[..., last] = array
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.

Comment: It's self explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slice` to get **last element**. In javascript, `slice` can pass negative number like -1 as arguments.

For example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3 ]
console.log "first: #{array[0]}"
console.log "last: #{array[-1..][0]}"
```

be compiled into

```
var array;
array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("first: " + array[0]);
console.log("last: " + array.slice(-1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `element` and the `index` of the current `element` when iterating through the array using Coffeescript's `for...in`. See the following code, replace the `special_process_for_element` and `normal_process_for_element` with your code.

```
array = [a, b, c, d]
FIRST_INDEX = 0
LAST_INDEX = array.length - 1

for element, index in array
    switch index
        when FIRST_INDEX, LAST_INDEX
            special_process_for_element
        else
            normal_process_for_element
```

[sample](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aarray%20%3D%20%5Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d%5D%0AFIRST_INDEX%20%3D%200%0ALAST_INDEX%20%3D%20array.length%20-%201%0A%0Afor%20element%2C%20index%20in%20array%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20index%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%20FIRST_INDEX%2C%20LAST_INDEX%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20special_process_for_element%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20normal_process_for_element)

Here's a [working code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aarray%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%2C%20%27d%27%2C%20%27e%27%5D%0AFIRST_INDEX%20%3D%200%0ALAST_INDEX%20%3D%20array.length%20-%201%0A%0Afor%20element%2C%20index%20in%20array%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20index%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%20FIRST_INDEX%2C%20LAST_INDEX%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22special%20%23%7Belement%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22normal%20%23%7Belement%7D%22%0A)